# How do I get a bool value from unknown form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a

```
foreach (Form discoveredForm in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (discoveredForm.Name != "MainForm")
    {
        discoveredForm.Hide();
    }
}
```

And discoveredForm has a

```
public bool isRenamed;
```

So, is that possible to get the bool value (isRenamed) from the discoveredForm?

Comment: isRenamed should be a Property, not a field.  Are all the forms you are hiding the same type?  If not, what type has the isRenamed field?

Comment: Take a look at the Reflection classes. They let you discover properties, methods etc of classes at run-time.

Comment: Alternately, create an inherited version of the base Form class, with this property, and adjust the forms that need it to inherit from this class.

Comment: I suggest writing an interface `interface IRenamable { bool IsRenamed { get; set; } }`, and implementing it in each form. Then iterate like so: `foreach (Form discoveredForm in Application.OpenForms) { if (discoveredForm is IRenamable ir) { ... } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I think this may help you.
Though you will want to know the name of the form before you do so

```
            foreach (Form discoveredForm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (discoveredForm.Name != "MainForm")
            {
             var S = (Form2)discoveredForm;
             MessageBox.Show(S.isRenamed.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Now I know that the other form I am looking for is named Form2, but I haven't a clue how many is open but this will hit on every one of them and display the value of the Boolean. If you want to change the bool just do this

```
            foreach (Form discoveredForm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (discoveredForm.Name != "MainForm")
            {
                discoveredForm.Hide();
                var S = (Form2)discoveredForm;
                S.isRenamed = True;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's a bad way to use Try-Catch.  You can simply check the type.